# Why can't I change tmp_upload_dir

Tags: php, ajax, apache, nginx, plesk

What I try to accomplish: Upload images from a web page via POST Request to my server and manipulate them.

I have been experiencing the following issue for a few days now:
I cannot access the uploads located in the "/tmp" folder using PHP.

Error message (XXXXX = domain name):

`Warning: getimagesize(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/phpQ3Y7XN/image.png) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/: /tmp/:/tmp/*) Warning: getimagesize(/tmp/phpQ3Y7XN/image.png): Failed to open stream: Operation not permitted`

As the dir /tmp exists within the configured open_basedir parameter, I do not understand what's going on here.

I am completely stuck here. Either not having permission

- Debian 11.7
- Plesk Obsidian 18.0.58 Update #2 with ModSecurity
- PHP 8.3.3 (Dedicated FPM-Application)
  Does anyone have an advice on this?

Any help is appreciated :)

- I tried to change upload_tmp_dir within my domains php.ini file to a path within the document root.
  For some reason this has no effect either. Uploads are still being moved to /tmp automatically.
- I also tried tepmporarely disabling ModSecurity as this has a SecUpload Policy. This had not effect whatsoever.
- I restarted the system.

Comment: Get rid of the space between `:` and `/tmp/` in `open_basedir`.

Comment: I don't think `*` has any special meaning in `open_basedir`, so `/tmp/*` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: Do you see the expected result if you do `var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply! Yes, the correct result is shown in frontend. I also noticed the following: Whenever I change tmp_upload_dir in php.ini. phpinfo() displays the correct dir., but when I do var_dump(sys_get_temp_dir()); it displays the wrong one: /tmp.

Comment: The temp directory is not the same as the temp upload directory.

Comment: @Barmar I think I might have noticed something important. Whenever a file is uploaded a unique folder is cretated. Like /tmp/phpgSuOY/<FILE_NAME>.

Maybe this could be the reason why Im not allowed to process the file. Is there any ways to use wildcards in open_basedir?

Comment: Wildcards are not needed. `open_basedir` includes subdirectories.

Comment: Have you read the documentation, it specifically says "directory-tree" -- that means the directory and all levels of subdirectory below it.

Comment: I am really confused on why this is happening then `File(/tmp/phpcvV9r4/default_file_icon.png) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/<DOMAIN>/:/tmp/)`

Comment: I'm not sure, either. I think it should work. If you remove `open_basedir` entirely does it work? I'm not suggesting this as a permanent solution, just a test.

Comment: @Barmar It sort of works after disabling open_basedir...? sys_get_temp_dir() differs from the files "tmp_name".... but not restriction in effect

Comment: Sort of works? Do you get an error or not? sys_get_temp_dir() has little to do with this.